# adding picture asynchronously doesn't show it self

Tags: ios

in my view did load : I calling for a function that fetches an image from URL (async)
but sometimes I do see the picture and sometimes I do not

my code 
in viewDidLoad

```
if(entry.length > 0)
{
    [self getPicture];
}
else
{
    ProfilePicure.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_man.png"];
}
 [topView addSubview:ProfilePicure];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xffffff)];
[self.view addSubview:topView];
```

the fetching function:

```
   - (void) getPicture
  {
  [WebImageOperations loadFromURL:entry andBlock:^(UIImage *imageData).
  {
     if (self.view.window)
     {
         UIImage *image1 = imageData;
         ProfilePicure.image = image1;
     }
  }];
   //Tried to add those to be able to see the picture, but sometimes i can't see 
 [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
 [topView addSubview:ProfilePicure];
 [topView setNeedsDisplay];
  }
```

Edit: adding the fetch function , I copied from this site and using it to fetch the image.

```
   + (void)loadFromURL:(NSString *)urlString andBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *image))processImage
 {
     NSMutableString *urlSTR =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [urlSTR appendString:@"http://www.ifat.com/files/infor/Person/"];
    [urlSTR appendString:urlString];
    NSURL *urlGet = [NSURL URLWithString:urlSTR];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlGet];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        processImage(image);
     });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need to check the url if it contains sapce in url for which you cant get image. if so then you need to use

```
urlSTR = [urlSTR stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

put this line after

```
[urlSTR appendString:@"http://www.ifat.com/files/infor/Person/"];
[urlSTR appendString:urlString];
```

and check it. this might help.

you have made simple things complicated. you can download image from url easily..

```
NSMutableString *urlSTR =[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[urlSTR appendString:@"http://smartradio.ch/APPETLM/admin/media_files/event/thumb/aaa162635eda024ee7dd908554b1b6cb.jpg"];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlSTR stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( data == nil )
        ProfilePicure.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_man.png"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
        ProfilePicure.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];


    });

});
```

put this in your view did load. first check it with some static url image then implement your urls

Comment: The URLs are ok , I can see the picture as a data , when I logging it , the problem is I can't make my top view to draw it when it gets downloaded .

Comment: UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        processImage(image); instead of this two line try  ProfilePicure.image =[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

Comment: It is not in the same class.

Comment: In previous view I used reloadData with this image fetcher and it worked well in table view.

Answer (score 1):

You MUST commit all UI updates on the main thread. For example set the image in the callback block with this:

```
[ProfilePicture performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:image1 waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to iOS could you please specify where should I put this, in the fetch function ? or in the view did load ?
or better could you please please write how I do this completely ?

Comment: Instead of `ProfilePicure.image = image1;`

Comment: I have done what you suggested , but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue :(